# How to get users greater than 25 years but i have only DOB column in mongoDB. how can i get in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query

dob is date of birth and dob column in only dob's year

**This is my code**

```
$voters = DB::collection('users')->whereDate(Carbon::parse('dob')->age, '<', 25)->get();
```

**This is my table**

```
id, name, dob
1, Peter, 1974
2, John, 1988
3, Semi, 1995
```

Comment: Is `dob` just a year?

Comment: This question lacks proper context, what is dob?

Comment: yes @BenHillier dob in only year

Comment: hello @YagoRiveiro dob is date of birth's year

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$filterYear = $now->year - 25;
$voters = DB::collection('users')->where('dob', '<', $filterYear)->get();
```

Please dont forget to use Carbon on top of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the years difference:

```
$voters = DB::collection('users')->whereDate(Carbon::now()->year - 25, '>', 'dob')->get();
```